# Exploratory data analysis. What features are important?

Tags: regression, cross-validation, multicollinearity, aic, variance-inflation-factor

I am trying to fit the number of crimes in a city with some enviromental variables (aka my features). I'm using a Poisson/Negative Binomial model since I have count data.
The problems are:

1. selecting the features which REALLY fit (I have sometimes big collinearity)
2. select the smallest subset of significative features (p-values)
3. understand the relative importance between them to fit the number of crimes

Possible solutions to the problems:

1. Variance inflation factor (VIF). **Is it ok?** Sometimes interactions could be ignored. I mean: what if I have to test whenever two variabiles are important, but collinear? (e.g. population density and employment density)
2. Stepwise (backward/foward/with Cross-Validation) steps to reduce the AIC. **However**, this does not mean that the resulting variables are significative (p-values). Should I care at all about the features' p-values?
3. Standardize the input data, then looking at the Beta coefficient to see the importance of them. **Is it really the best way?**

Should I use something else?
Keep in mind that my primary goal is not the $R^2$. I want to see and to be able to explain how some variables could explain the crime.